Want to host a Netlify app in squarespace domain without affecting google workspace
We recently purchased a domain on Google Workspace in order to use email and other services. Squarespace provides the domain name. Google email and site configuration are already shown in the DNS settings. Email will not function if I modify the DNS and point it to my web application to use Netlify.
Despite the perplexing new collaboration between Google Workspace and Squarespace, how can I install my Netlify app that is referred to the Squarespace domain without affecting Google email services?

You need to add an entry to DNS Settings (Squarespace)
Host = @, Type = A, Data = 75.2.60.5
As well as the CNAME record for www
Host = www, Type = CNAME, Data = your-site-name.netlify.app
It is better to remove the previous Type = A
and also, if there was an entry for Host = www, then delete it too, since you will not be able to make a new entry for Host = www
